# Angular Front - NEST JS on Cloud Functions - has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors, nestjs

I have a forehead in ANGULAR - IONIC.
I have an API with NESTJS.
I hosted the API on the cloud functions of firebase with this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IVy3Tm8iHQ0&ab_channel=Fireship

When I run the API locally (npm a start) it works perfectly!
I have a system for the cors which is the following (stored in main.ts):

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('MY WEB API')
    .setDescription('READ ONLY')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addTag('TAG')
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
  SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);

  app.use(helmet());

  const whitelist = ['http://localhost:8100/', 'http://localhost:8100', '*'];
  app.enableCors({
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
      if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
        console.log('allowed cors for:', origin);
        callback(null, true);
      } else {
        console.log('blocked cors for:', origin);
        callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
      }
    },
    allowedHeaders:
      'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept, Observe',
    methods: 'GET, OPTIONS',
    credentials: true,
  });

  await app.listen(3000);
}

bootstrap();
```

Unfortunately when I run the api on the firebase environment (firebase serve --only functions) I get the following error:

[image]

(I checked, I can use it well with Postman)
I have tried many things to fix that:

Directly from the controller

```
  @Get('ByName')
  @Header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://localhost:8100')
  async findByName(@Query('name') name: string) {
    return await this.personnesService.findByName(name);
  }
```

Desactivate the cors

```
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    logger: console,
    cors: false,
  });
```

Activate them like that

```
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  const corsOptions = {
    methods: 'GET',
    preflightContinue: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
    credentials: true,
    origin: ['http://localhost:8100/', 'http://localhost:8100'],
  };

  app.enableCors(corsOptions);
```

I've checked on the cloud functions, the code is up to date (you never know!) and the requests arrive well.
In fact, when I launch the request and I get the error, the API still executes the request (a console.log in the API allows to check it) but doesn't seem to return the result, from what I understand because of the cors.
In reality, it doesn't go through the main.ts either since this console.log doesn't appear. I don't know how to make it go through there.

**How can I activate the cors (or deactivate them?) so I don't get the error anymore?**

Some information about my versions:

```
NESTJS API : 
"@nestjs/common": "^7.5.1",
"firebase-functions": "^3.13.0",
"@types/express": "^4.17.8",
"typescript": "^4.0.5
"node": "12"

My FRONT:
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.0",
"ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I now understand my mistake. My configuration is correct, but it's not in the right place to make it work in production!

In a classic NESTJS application, the main.ts is used to launch the application. In my case, having followed this tutorial https://fireship.io/snippets/setup-nestjs-on-cloud-functions/, the index.ts replaces the main.ts.

So the solution is to move my configuration to the **index.ts**!

Here is my new function.

```
const server = express();

export const createNestServer = async (expressInstance) => {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(
    AppModule,
    new ExpressAdapter(expressInstance),
  );

  const corsOptions = {
    methods: 'GET',
    preflightContinue: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
    credentials: true,
    origin: ['http://localhost:8100/', 'http://localhost:8100'],
  };

  app.enableCors(corsOptions);

  return app.init();
};

createNestServer(server)
  .then((v) => console.log('Nest Ready'))
  .catch((err) => console.error('Nest broken', err));

export const api = functions.https.onRequest(server);
```

Don't forget to build before relaunching!

```
npm run build
firebase serve --only functions
firebase deploy --only functions
```